How to obtain this expression of the Reynolds number for evaporating falling films?
The Reynolds number for evaporating falling films on a vertical plate is expressed as
$$\mathrm{Re}=\frac{4\Gamma}{\mu}$$
but what are the steps that would take me from the common formula for the Reynolds number to this one?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
